# Compile on RHLE6, but run on RHEL7 or Fedora 29 - is that possible?

Tags: fedora, rhel, compatibility

I was wondering in terms of system compatibility.

If I compile an application on RHEL6 - would I be able to safely run the output on RHEL7 and/or Fedora 29 as well, if I copy both the binary as well as of all its dynamically linked (non-system) libraries over to the RHEL7 or Fedora 29 machine?

I'm guessing here for a bit, but my understanding is that both the binary file itself, as well as its dynamically linked libraries should load on either system. I'm not sure on the system librarise (in /lib or /lib64 etc) though, assuming I'm not using some chroot, I assume those will differ between the systems, could that cause issues? Or could I expect these on RHEL7 and Fedora29 to be fully compatible to RHEL6?

Comment: You're better off doing static linking if this is your goal.